# Circular div to expand about the middle point, not the top edge

Tags: css

I need a circular div to expand about the middle point, not the top edge!

I have a circle that is 100px by 100px with border-radius of 50%

I want it to expand to 500x500 when hovered over, I have done the hovering part. 
However when the circle expands it expands about the mid point of the old, smaller circle!
Is there a way to set a new midpoint in the :hover or specify a certain place etc.

Code:

```
    .circle1
{
margin-top:50%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50%;
background: #ff3019; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%, #cf0404 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff3019), color-stop(100%,#cf0404)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 100%); /* W3C */  

transition:1s;
-moz-transition: 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: 1s; /* Opera */
-ms-transition: 1s; /* IE9 (maybe) */

}

.circle1:hover
{
width:500px;
height:500px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply relative positioning to the circle, and offset it on hover:

```
.circle1
{
     position:relative;
     /* etc. */
}

.circle1:hover
{
   top:-200px;
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
}
```

see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/mhfaust/L2McU/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the change in dimension to change the layout (other elements position), keep your solution.

If not, apply transforms:

```
transform: scale (5, 5);
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```